# Подключиться к SAS из Java

Tags: java, oracle, sas

Имеется SAS (7 версии), БД Oracle. Есть необходимость получать данные из SAS инициируя запрос из Oracle. В связи с этим возникла идея написать на Java метод, который подключаться к SAS и забирать данные из нужного дата-сета. Кто-нибудь делал такое? Ткните в пример пожалуйста, как из Java подключиться к SAS и забрать данные в БД?

Comment: Приветствую. [Вот](https://sites.google.com/site/stamb2012/examples) интересный материал. Нашел даже [библиотеку](http://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/parso.html) для чтения

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что версия SAS 7 никогда не выходила публично.  Предполагая, что имелись в виду Java 7 и SAS 9, посмотрите примеры [тут](https://go.documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/jdbcref/9.4/content/jdbcref.pdf).

Вот один из примеров:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class accessSASData {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Connection connection;
        Properties props;
        int i;
        Statement statement;
        String queryString = "SELECT sup_id, sup_name " + "FROM mySasLib.suppliers ORDER BY sup_name";
        ResultSet result;
        double id;
        String name;
        try {
            //CONNECT TO THE SERVER BY USING A CONNECTION PROPERTY LIST
            Class.forName("com.sas.rio.MVADriver");
            props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "jdoe");
            props.setProperty("password", "4ht8d");
            props.setProperty("librefs", "mySasLib c:\\sasdata';");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sasiom://c123.na.abc.com:8591", props);
            //ACCESS DATA
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
            while (result.next()) {
                id = result.getDouble(1);
                name = result.getString(2);
                System.out.println(id + " " + name);
            }
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)